# How to reference a file for variables using ksh?

Tags: ksh

How do I reference a variable from another file using ksh?

I know in bash you just use "source script" and then "echo $variable"
but in ksh, when I try that, it does not work.

example I am trying to do:

**config.sh:**

```
variable=apple
```

**access_var.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
source config.sh
echo $variable
```

in ksh I just get " config.sh: cannot open [No such file or directory]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a path for to the file. If the file is in the current directory use `source ./config.sh`. Otherwise an absolute or relative path is OK, the latter must not start with `./`.

If you don't provide a path `ksh` searches the file in the directories in `$PATH`.

(And remember to change the shebang in the other script to whereever your `ksh` is (or make sure your scripts are POSIX shell compatible and just use `#!/bin/sh` to have scripts with a high chance to run everywhere).)

Comment: That did the trick! Wow, so simple, clearly I'm a newb haha. Thanks so much!